# Best way to organize data cleanup logic in JS?

Tags: javascript, data-cleaning

I'm importing personal finance data from the Plaid API and dumping it into a Google Sheet.

Right now, I'm feeding the transaction data through an "algorithm" which is essentially a function comprised of a bunch of if else statements. For example, if the Plaid category is "Shoe Store" change it to "Clothing and Accessories".

I know it's probably easiest to move this data into a SQL database and clean it up there (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I'd like to keep this in Google Sheets as the data needs to be easily accessible by my partner.

This feels terribly messy, and there's got to be a better way to do it in JS.

Comment: The cleanup logic won't be much different or any shorter if you do it in an SQL database, or any other language for that matter, instead of JS. What exactly feels so messy about it? Can you post that "*function comprised of a bunch of if else statements*" that you need help with? Sounds like it might be appropriate at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) will allow you to connect to Plaid and pull the data (including filters / algorithms) into a Sheet.

Also, if you're more comfortable Python, [this app](https://www.wax.run/) lets you run Python within a Sheet.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'm already using apps script to connect to Plaid and pull the data. My question is more around how to best organize filters/algorithms within apps script. Unless you're talking about a library/integration I am not aware of?

Comment: @user12457151 Got it. Have you used Pandas? It's very good for creating filters. There is a JS version here that I've gotten working in Apps Script before, but the original is written in Python. https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/08/introducing-danfo-js-pandas-like-library-in-javascript.html

Comment: By the way, is Plaid free for personal use?

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks! I've heard of pandas but have never tried it out myself. I'll give the JS version a look. Plaid is free for personal use as a developer account